# Monitor request lastency and missing datapoints

Tags: python, grafana, prometheus

I'm trying to monitor request latency using`Summary` type and show percentiles using Grafana.

I'm using `prometheus_client version 0.5.0`. This is how I configured the metric

```py
sample_processing_summary = Summary("sample_processing_3_summary_seconds", "Sample processing latency", ["sample_type"])
```

And this how I'm using it:

```py
def message_processor(message, rat):
    with metrics.sample_processing_summary.labels(rat).time():
        do_process_message(message, rat)
```

Now I'm trying to show 99th percentiles. In the [tutorial](https://github.com/danielfm/prometheus-for-developers) I've read was PromQl query

```
sample_app_summary_request_duration_seconds{quantile="0.99"}
```

But this does not works because I have only `sample_processing_3_summary_seconds_count`, `sample_processing_3_summary_seconds_sum` and `sample_processing_3_summary_seconds_created` datapoints.

How to show 99th percentiles in Grafana using Prometheus and Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python client doesn't support quantiles for the `Summary` currently.

What you want to do is use a `Histogram` and then `histogram_quantile(0.99, rate(histogram_name_bucket[5m]))`.

Comment: :( To use histogram I have to provide buckets that I don't known jet

Comment: I've created some buckets `buckets=[5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 150, 300]` and executed query you have provided bu the result is `17.5`

This mean that 99% of requests finish in <= 17.5 ms? I haven't provided this bucket. The response shouln't be 20?

Comment: The way `histogram_quantile` works is that first it identifies the range that the requested percentile falls into (say 96% of the requests took less than 10ms and 100% took less than 20ms, then the range is 10-20ms). The second step is to do a linear interpolation between the two buckets and estimate where your specific percentile falls. (In my example before, a linear interpolation between 96% and 100% would estimate the 99th percentile at 17.5.) It is an estimate though, so the only thing you can say with certainty is that the 99th percentile is somewhere between 10ms and 20ms.

Comment: Oh, and as a side note, you should use base units (i.e. seconds, not milliseconds) as bucket boundaries, same as you would with metric values. It saves a lot of confusion.